# How to show: $f$ is surjective $\iff $ for every generator $G\subset X$ of $X$, $f(G)\subset Y$ is a generator of $Y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $X$, $Y$ are two $F$-linear Spaces. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a $F$-linear. Show that the following conditions are equivalent:

i) $f$ is surjective;

ii) $R(f)=Y$,  where $R(f)=\mathrm{Im}(f)=f(X)$;

iii) For every generator $G\subset X$ of X is $f(G)\subset Y$ a generator of $Y$.

i) $\iff$ ii) is trivial, since $R(f)=Y$ is only true if and only if $f$ is surjective.

I don't know how to show i) or ii)$\iff$iii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that with “generator” you mean “generating set” (or “spanning set”).

You're correct in saying that (i) is trivially equivalent to (ii), which is just a rephrasing.

Suppose (iii). In particular, $f(X)$ is a generating set for $Y$, because $X$ is a generating set for $X$. Therefore $f$ is surjective.

Suppose $f$ is surjective and that $G$ is a generating set for $X$. We need to show that $f(G)$ is a generating set for $Y$. Let $y\in Y$; then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Since $G$ is a generating set for $X$, we can write
$$
x=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dots+\alpha_kx_k
$$
for $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k\in G$ and scalars $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k\in F$. Then
$$
y=f(x)=\alpha_1f(x_1)+\alpha_2f(x_2)+\dots+\alpha_kf(x_k)
$$
belongs to the subspace generated by $f(G)$ and therefore this subspace is $Y$.

Comment: Hi, this looks very analog to some other proof my prof has in the script. I simply dont understand why you can write y in the way you do there. can you explain that?

Comment: @saturatedexpo $y=f(x)$ by assumption; substitute $x=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dots+\alpha_kx_k$ and use the fact that $f$ is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be surjective and $G\subseteq X$ any generator of $X$. Let $y\in Y$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is an $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$. Since $G$ is a generator of $X$ there exist $a_1,...,a_n\in F$ and $g_1,...,g_n\in G$ with $$a_1 g_1+\cdots+a_n g_n =x.$$ Apply $f$ to this equation: $$y=f(x)=a_1 f(g_1)+\cdots+a_n f(g_n).$$ Therefore any $y\in Y$ is a finite linear combination of elements of $f(G)$. So, $f(G)$ is generator of $Y$.

On the other hand, let's assume (iii) holds. Let $y\in Y$ any element and let $G$ be generator of $X$. By assumption $f(G)$ is generator of $Y$. We have to show that there exists $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$. This far, we know there are some $a_1,...,a_n\in F$ and $h_1,...,h_n\in f(G)$ with $$y=a_1 h_1 +\cdots+a_n h_n.$$ Since $h_i\in f(G)$, there's a $g_i\in G$ with $f(g_i)=h_i$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$. Therefore we have:$$y=a_1f(g_1)+\cdots+a_n f(g_n)=f(a_1 g_1 +\cdots+a_n g_n)$$. This shows $f$ is surjective.